# Best approach to combine frameworks in github?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I'm new to git, and having done a fair bit of reading up I've set up a github account ready to get started.

I plan to combine elements of [Inuit.css](https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css) with [Bones](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones) to create my own starter framework for Wordpress projects.

My question is should I fork each of these projects and clone them locally, then edit/combine and upload to a new repository? The help info regarding forking appears to imply that you would fork a repository when you were looking to contribute to the original repository rather than create a derivative work, or perhaps that is just the most common use case?

The other option I can see is to just download the repository for each as a zip file, combine/edit and then upload them to a new repository.

Is there a benefit to either route or perhaps another approach that I might be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd create derivative work anyways. So forking and downloading and uploading to completely new repo either one sounds okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If -- and this is a big if -- you just need to bring in elements from each framework, without modifying the files in either, then you might consider using git submodules. See e.g. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules for details.

Comment: Thanks this looks like it might be worth looking into for inuit.css, as I won't need to change those files, but I'm fairly likely to want to be able to edit the files from Bones. I assume the reason you can't edit the files in submodules is simply so that you can bring in 'upstream' changes from their project repositories, which makes sense. 

So what would be the best approach in the situation that I need to edit the files?

Comment: Submodules are simply ways for repos to point to specific versions of other repos. In this case it sounds like you can point directly to the intuit.css repo, but Bones may require changes. In that case, you have two options OTOH, both involving a fork of Bones: create a repo for your own project and point to intuit (stock) and Bones (your fork); or fork Bones and have the forked copy refer to the stock intuit.css repo. Depends on how deep your modifications to Bones will go.

Comment: So if I use a submodule approach for inuit does that limit my ability to pull in updates to my submodule of inuit when the original inuit repo is updated to a new version by the developer?

Comment: Your repo will contain a hash that identifies the version of the submodule that it wants to attach to. If you want to update to a newer version, go into the submodule directory and pull the updates in as you would any git repository; then in your own repository, use "git add path/to/submodule; git commit -m 'submodule update'" so that your repo refers to the newer submodule.